# LVM - New PVS or resize PVS - Centos 7

Tags: lvm, centos-7

I got a doubt:

If you already have a Volume Group but you need to increase it, with regard to disk performance, would it be suitable add a second physical volumen to the Volume Group?

Thanks!

Regards

Comment: if you are talking about real hardware physical drives - you can't resize them. if you are talking about VM disks used for pvs then they are virtualized and depending if you use thin or thick provisioning somewhere on your storage so the performance does not involve as much the pvs as it does where and how you have your vmdk's or whatever format you use. If you could broaden your question with more information and what you want to achieve?

Comment: You have a Volume group with a pvs which is full. You have two choices to increase the Volume Group:  1- Add a new pvs . 2- Increase the current pvs. Which option is the best with regard to disk performance?